# How can I reload a modified resource in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension and I need to modify a resource and reload the page with the modified resource. I may be going about this all wrong.

```
  if(injectFile) {
    injectFile.getContent(function(content) {
      content = 'window.alert("hi");' + content;
      injectFile.setContent(content, true, function() {
        chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload({
          ignoreCache: true
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The reason is because I want to add benchmarking to the selected file. I can modify the resource but it's pointless if I can't add my benchmarking script before the resource is loaded.

I've also gone the route of trying to modify the content of a request for the resource in my background script but it doesn't look like I can programmatically reload the page to kickstart the http requests.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "modify a resource".  Content scripts modify the html page; that's pretty much their reason for existence.  You can also use them to reload a page.  `chrome.tabs` can also probably reload a page, although I'm not as sure about that.  Can you clarify what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm wanting to wrap some of angulars native watch functions to benchmark their performance. The only way I can do this is to modify the angular.js file before the browser loads it.

Comment: @Teepeemm I want to use `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow` to 1. find the angular.js resource file then 2. modify it contents and ultimately 3. reload the page with the modified contents. If there is another way to do this I will try that- but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I don't think Chrome can modify a javascript file before loading it.  Are the modifications dynamic?  Or would you be able to make the modifications in your text editor?

Comment: @Teepeemm You would be able to make the modifications in a text editor.